# Is it possible to trigger a Redis JS function from Redis pubsub

Tags: javascript, redis

With the introduction of the new JS Redis Functions https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/
It seems possible to move some logic completely into Redis.
What I haven't found is if it is possible to use Redis PubSub as trigger for any Redis script JS or Lua. From the official docs it looks like PubSub is completely separate from the rest of Redis.
Is there a possibility to execute a function triggered by pubsub events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, although that's an interesting idea.

Right now functions can only be [triggered](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/concepts/triggers/) by [user invocation](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/concepts/triggers/user_functions/), [when an event is added to a stream](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/concepts/triggers/stream_triggers/), and on [keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/triggers-and-functions/concepts/triggers/keyspace_triggers/).

Comment: Yeah, what I'm doing right now is writing a small daemon that listens on pubsub and forwards the data to a Redis Stream.
It would be really amazing if you could connect pubsub to streams internally.

Comment: That's probably the best solution given what triggers can do right now. The only other I can think of would be to just use a Redis Stream *instead* of PubSub. Although that does force all clients that want to consume that Stream to the same shard.